Failed to connect to my Github Account with 2FA enabled
I had to get a new phone and at the same time I've lost my 2FA to connect to my Github account over the web.
Meanwhile I'm still using vscode and Github Desktop to push and pull items.
Is there anyone who has seen this issu and how to restore the situation as I don't have any recovery codes?
I have contacted GitHub support but am still waiting for their advice.
